# vba for Internet explorer - How to show error message box when Dropdown selected for month is empty

Tags: excel, vba

Here you have my code. I've put some remarks where I need to do check the empty dropdownlist.

```
Dim IE As Object Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim chromePath As String

     Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
     IE.Navigate "https://www.facebook.com/"      
     IE.Visible = True

Dim doc As Object

     IE.Top = 0
     IE.Left = 0
     IE.Width = 1200
     IE.Height = 1000
     IE.AddressBar = 0
     IE.StatusBar = 0
     IE.Toolbar = 0
     IE.Visible = True
     With IE
          Do
               If IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
                    IE.Visible = True
                    Exit Do
               Else
                    DoEvents
               End If
          Loop
          DoEvents
          Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
          IE.Document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex = -2
          '(Here i want to check if the selected dropdown is blank as in case
          'of month on facebook I want to show some error and also want to do
          'some more action) 'On Error GoTo Prob MsgBox "Code has completed"
          'Exit Sub
          'Prob: MsgBox Err.Description & " has prevented the code completing"
     End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If (IE.Document.getElementById("month").value = 0) Then
'or null, Empty, etc depending on element type (for combo it's 0th item)
     Call MsgBox ("The message box")
     'the other things you want to do
End If
```

Comment: In this if I am selecting 0 it gives me "Month" but if I am selecting a value which is out of scope please consider it as -2(any value which out of scope from the drop downlist) than you will get the "empty box" selected in place of "Month". so now I might have any value say -2 or -3 or -4..,15,18,19 and so on I will get the same "empty box" this needs to handled and lastly in this case we are just dealing with integers but I want the same comparison for strings ad there are many number of strings. so If there is any partucular null value of the selected "empty box" this will definately work

Comment: But I dont what can be the value of the "empty box" so I am failing to proceed further so can you please help

Comment: @user2485794 I'm not sure I understand you... I added the ".value" to the "getElementById" call which means it shows the value of the dropdown. And this was your question... "i want to check if the selected dropdown is blank" (on FB example 'Month' means blank / left empty)

Comment: Sorry If i have confused you.....actually I will be using some thing like this Range("D1").Select
    Name = activeCell.Value
          IE.Document.getElementById("day").Value = Name
       
       
       
       If (IE.Document.getElementById("day").Value = Name) Then
       'Call MsgBox("The message box")
            MsgBox ("worked ")
            
        Else
        MsgBox ("Not worked ")
        End If

Comment: In this I will be taking some value from excel will try to select the dropdown if the selected dropdown and the given dropdown matched than it should show worked or else not worked,

Comment: for Day I have took 4 in "D1" but it showed me than "Not worked" but as the value is present in Day than ideally it should work.